# ReactJS with Bootstrap dropdown (not using react-bootstrap): Bind to aria-expanded in property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using React with bootstrap (not react-bootstrap). I want to expose the value of the aria-expanded attribute to the parent of the component, but with code like the following, it seems that even when the attribute changes in the DOM, it's not cascading the update. Any suggestions? The code looks like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{
...
    isExpanded: boolean
}, {

    }>
{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        ...
        return <div className="btn-group position-button-group float-right">
            <button className="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle position-button" title="My Dropdown"
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded={this.props.isExpanded}>
                ...
            </button>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: [It seems to work for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2km66myzq).

Comment: Can you confirm, does it update after you open the modal to the Boolean value 'true' ? Or is it only on start that it assigns the initial value to that attribute?